# Большое число.c++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, олимпиада

Большое число

Вася написал на длинной полоске бумаги большое число и решил похвастаться своему старшему брату Пете этим достижением. Но только он вышел из комнаты, чтобы позвать брата, как его сестра Катя вбежала в комнату и разрезала полоску бумаги на несколько частей. В результате на каждой части оказалось одна или несколько идущих подряд цифр. Теперь Вася не может вспомнить, какое именно число он написал. Только помнит, что оно было очень большое и, разумеется, не начиналось с нуля. Чтобы утешить младшего брата, Петя решил выяснить, какое максимальное число могло быть написано на полоске бумаги перед разрезанием. Помогите ему!

Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных содержится натуральное число N, не превосходящее 100 — количество строк. Далее заданы N строк, каждая из которых содержит последовательность цифр. Каждая строка содержит от 1 до 100 цифр. Гарантируется, что хотя бы в одной строке первая цифра отлична от нуля.

Выходные данные

Выведите одну строку — максимальное число, которое могло быть написано на полоске перед разрезанием.

Примеры

Ввод

4

2

20

004

66

Вывод

66220004

Единственное, что пока получилось - написать 3 функции, не факт, что относящихся к правильному решению задачи:

```
using namespace std;
long long pow(long long a, long long n){
    long long res=1;
    for(long long i=0; i<n; ++i){
        res*=a;
    }
    return res;
}
long long count_of_digits(long long n){
    long long c=0;
    while(n>0){
        n/=10;
        ++c;
    }
    return c;
}
long long nth_digit(long long n, i){
    return n/pow(10, count_of_digits(n)-i)%10;
}
```

Изначально у меня была следующая идея решения задачи:

Отсортировать эти отрезки в двумерном массиве по первым цифрам и "склеить" их в один массив. Если первые цифры равны, то сортировать по следующим неравным цифрам. Затем я выяснил, что такой алгоритм некорректен.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту задачу идейно, дайте, если не сложно, предпосылку к решению этой задачи.

Comment: В Бусте есть либа для очень больших чисел

Comment: Это явно не на знание библиотек. по формулировке задача очень напоминает задачи начального уровня по data science. Ну и вообще - все эти "пети васи" - это из олимпиадных задач :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто строки, не нужно никакой длинной арифметики...

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> A;
    string s;
    while(cin >> s) A.push_back(s);
    for(int j = A.size()-1; j >= 0; --j)
        for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            if (A[i+1]+A[i] > A[i]+A[i+1])
                swap(A[i],A[i+1]);
    for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); ++j)
        cout << A[j];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое

Answer (score 0):

***Harry*** - ну, Вы крутой!

я решил, что это задачка на рекурсию.
некотрые "лишние" переменные оставлены в коде, чтобы проще было посмотреть по шагам в дебаггере

Мой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string BuildMax(const vector<string>& src){
    if (src.size()==1) return src[0];
    vector<string> lst;
    for( int i=0; i<src.size(); ++i ){
        // строим список всех элементов кроме выбранного
        vector<string> tmp;
        for( int j=0; j<src.size(); ++j )
            if(j!=i)
                tmp.push_back(src[j]);
        string stp = BuildMax(tmp);
        string nxt = src[i] + stp;
        lst.push_back(nxt);
    };
    // теперь в списке lst - все варианты, котрые могут быть построены
    // сортируем список в лексикографическом порядке и возвращаем максимальный (последний) элемент
    sort(lst.begin(), lst.end());
    return lst[lst.size()-1];
}

int main(){
    ifstream inp("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");

    int N;
    inp >> N;
    vector<string> src;
    string s;
    while(inp >> s) src.push_back(s);

    string rez = BuildMax(src);
    out << rez;

    return 0;
}
```